# Error Bars not displaying Seaborn Relplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, errorbar, relplot

Using this code I created a seaborn plot to visualize multiple variables in a long format dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Patient ID': [11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 22222, 22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333, 33333, 33333, 44444, 44444, 44444, 44444, 55555, 55555, 55555, 55555],
        'Lab Attribute': ['% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)'],
        'Baseline': [46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 56.0, 104.0, 31.0, 12.0, 50.0, 100.0, 33.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0],
        '3 Month': [33.0, 92.0, 19.0, 25.0, 33.0, 92.0, 21.0, 11.0, 33.0, 102.0, 18.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0],
        '6 Month': [34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# reshape the dataframe
dfm = df_labs.melt(id_vars=['Patient_ID', 'Lab_Attribute'], var_name='Months')

# change the Months values to numeric
dfm.Months = dfm.Months.map({'Baseline': 0, '3 Month': 3, '6 Month': 6})

# plot a figure level line plot with seaborn
p = sns.relplot(data=dfm, col='Lab_Attribute', x='Months', y='value', hue='Patient_ID', kind='line', col_wrap=5, marker='o', palette='husl',facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True},err_style="bars", ci=95,)

plt.savefig('gmb_nw_labs.jpg')
```

The plots work great, though for some reason the error bars are not displaying, even after adding:

```
err_style="bars", ci=95,
```

to sns.replot()

```
p = sns.relplot(data=dfm, col='Lab_Attribute', x='Months', y='value', hue='Patient_ID', kind='line', col_wrap=5, marker='o', palette='husl',facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True},err_style="bars", ci=95,)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is, are there maybe just too few data points in my data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Each datapoint is separated by `hue`, so there are no error bars because no data is being combined. Remove `hue='Patient ID'` to only show the mean line and error bars.
- Alternatively, [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) can be mapped onto the [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html). By not specifying `hue` the API will create the error bars

  - `linestyle=''` is specified so the mean line is not drawn
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
data = {'Patient ID': [11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 22222, 22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333, 33333, 33333, 44444, 44444, 44444, 44444, 55555, 55555, 55555, 55555],
        'Lab Attribute': ['% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)'],
        'Baseline': [46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 56.0, 104.0, 31.0, 12.0, 50.0, 100.0, 33.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0],
        '3 Month': [33.0, 92.0, 19.0, 25.0, 33.0, 92.0, 21.0, 11.0, 33.0, 102.0, 18.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0],
        '6 Month': [34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# reshape the dataframe
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Patient ID', 'Lab Attribute'], var_name='Months')

# change the Months values to numeric
dfm.Months = dfm.Months.map({'Baseline': 0, '3 Month': 3, '6 Month': 6})

# plot a figure level line plot with seaborn
p = sns.relplot(data=dfm, col='Lab Attribute', x='Months', y='value', hue='Patient ID', kind='line', col_wrap=3, marker='o', palette='husl', facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True}, err_style="bars", ci=95,)
p.map(sns.lineplot, 'Months', 'value',  linestyle='', err_style="bars", color='k')
```

[image]

- Original implementation without `hue='Patient ID'`

```py
p = sns.relplot(data=dfm, col='Lab Attribute', x='Months', y='value', kind='line', col_wrap=3, marker='o', palette='husl', facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True}, err_style="bars", ci=95)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, upgraded seaborn and matplotlib and restarted kernal and voila! Works perfectly. Thank you again for helping me today. This has been a big step forward in my data analysis skill set.